# textFieldShouldReturn didn't respond on my UITextField in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a `UITextField` in a `UITableViewCell` which are in a `UITableView` which is part of my `UIViewController`. `TextFields` are visible and I can click them (keyboard shows up) but method `textFieldShouldReturn` isn't work.
I make delegate like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
VVUserInformationCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellUserIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

[cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
cell.userData.delegate = self;

[cell.typeLabel setText: array[indexPath.row][0]];
[cell.userData setTextAlignment: NSTextAlignmentRight];

return cell;
```

}

```
-(BOOL)textfieldShouldReturn:(UITextField*)textField{
NSError* e = nil;
NSLog(@"HEJ!");

switch (textField.tag) {
    case 0:
        arrayStr = [textField.text componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
        self.currentAttendee.firstName = arrayStr[0];
        self.currentAttendee.lastName = arrayStr[1];
        break;

    case 1:
        self.currentAttendee.username = textField.text;
        break;

    case 2:
        self.currentAttendee.email = textField.text;
        break;

    case 3:
        arrayStr = [textField.text componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
        self.currentAttendee.firstName = arrayStr[0];
        self.currentAttendee.lastName = arrayStr[1];
        break;

    case 4:
        self.currentAttendee.username = textField.text;
        break;

    case 5:
        self.currentAttendee.email = textField.text;
        break;

    default:
        break;
}
[textField resignFirstResponder];
return YES;

[self.currentAttendee.managedObjectContext save:&e];
NSAssert(!e,@"Error saving to API: %@",e);
```

}

I made brakepoint inside of textfieldshould return but it didn't go there.

Edit: userData is my TextField.

Comment: Have you set textfield's delegate???

Answer (score 2):

Your method is:

```
- (BOOL)textfieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField;
```

The correct method is:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField;
```

They are different by the way ;)

Answer (score 0):

Where is your `UITextField`?

I don't see you setting it anywhere in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

In case you have it and it's a property on the cell you need to set it's delegate to the `UITableViewController`:

```
cell.textField.delegate = self;
```

Now your view controller will respond to `textfieldShouldReturn:`.

Also, ensure that your `UITableViewController` conforms to the UITextFieldDelegate protocol:

```
@interface MyTableViewController : UITableViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>

// ...

@end
```

Comment: userData is textField in this cell.